# Shrink Windows 10 ISO to a minimum

Tags: windows, virtual-machines, iso, shrink

I want to run Windows 10 on a virtual machine for automated testing. I only need Edge or IE installed and want the .iso file size to be as small as possible.

Is there a way to shrink the image by disabling the built-it Windows features, possibly even to less than one GB?

I would be really thankful for any possible solution to this problem!!

Answer (score 1):

Evaluation VMs of Windows 10 with Edge are available from Edge developer tools. http://modern.ie

Less than 1 GB is unrealistic for Windows, especially with desktop experience. Waiting for the download of a few GB will be less frustrating.

Answer (score 0):

The only version that is lighter is the LTSB or the [IoT](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot-core/windows-iot) version.

Which does not have the Windows Store support and they don't have Edge. (You can still install Chromium Edge)